# Netbeans CVS-client's commands

Tags: logging, cvs

I am trying to use CVS-client.jar of Netbeans to find specific project's users.

I tried to use the 'cvs history' command, to get history:

1. From -m **module**
2. Of -x **type**
3. By -a **(All users)**
4. On -D **date**

E.g.,

```
    cvs history -a -x AMR -m DemoModule -D 06/07/2011
```

But this command produces the following error message:

`cvs [server aborted]: Only one report type allowed from: "-Tcomxe"`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, the below will display results from a certain module,

**and** of only certain record types. The key is using `-n` in place of `-m`.

(`-n` doesn't appear to be listed in all CVS command listings I have found).

```
     cvs history -x AMR -a -n DemoModule -D 06/07/2011
```

Now, for the reason for the error that the OP, and I, got... From my versions man page:

`Usage: {cvs} history [-report] [-flags] [-options args] [files...]`

and

```
Several options (shown above as '-report') control what kind of report is generated:

-c
    Report on each time commit was used (i.e., each time the repository was modified). 

-e
    Everything (all record types). Equivalent to specifying `-x' with all record types.
    Of course, `-e' will also include record types which are added in a future version of
    CVS; if you are writing a script which can only handle certain record types, you'll 
    want to specify `-x'.

-m module
    Report on a particular module. (You can meaningfully use `-m' more than once on the command line.) 

-o
    Report on checked-out modules. 

-T
    Report on all tags.

-x type
    Extract a particular set of record types type from the CVS history.
    The types are indicated by single letters, which you may specify in combination. 

        Certain commands have a single record type:

        F  release 
        O  checkout 
        E  export 
        T  rtag 

        One of four record types may result from an update:

        C  A merge was necessary but collisions were detected (requiring manual merging). 
        G  A merge was necessary and it succeeded. 
        U  A working file was copied from the repository. 
        W  The working copy of a file was deleted during update (because it was gone from the repository). 

        One of three record types results from commit:

        A  A file was added for the first time. 
        M  A file was modified. 
        R  A file was removed.
```

Problem is, what isn't very well articulated in all the manuals I have seen, is that you can only have a single report type. i.e., **One** of the above main options (c, e, m, o, T, x), which is (perhaps too) clearly stated by the error `Only one report type allowed from: "-Tcomxe"`.

P.S the below have proved to be useful resources for CVS CLI / cvs history:

http://www.cs.utah.edu/dept/old/texinfo/cvs/cvs_18.html#SEC87

http://durak.org/sean/pubs/software/cvsbook/History-_002d_002d-A-Summary-Of-Repository-Activity.html

http://www.thathost.com/wincvs-howto/cvsdoc/cvs_16.html#SEC134

http://linuxdevcenter.com/pub/a/linux/2002/06/13/cvs.htm